# Trying to run a test for a java class in Spock framework but I get this weird error about the constructor

Tags: java, groovy, spock

This is the error I get when I try to create the class under test

```
Could not find matching constructor for: com.pittacode.apihelper.json.JsonObjectFlattener()
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: com.pittacode.apihelper.json.JsonObjectFlattener() at com.pittacode.apihelper.json.JsonObjectFlattenerTest.flatten json object with one nested object(JsonObjectFlattenerTest.groovy:12)
```

This is my test class

```
package com.pittacode.apihelper.json

import com.google.gson.JsonObject
import com.google.gson.JsonParser
import spock.lang.Specification

class JsonObjectFlattenerTest extends Specification {

    def classUnderTest = new JsonObjectFlattener()

    def "flatten json object with one nested object"() {
        given:
        def jsonString = """
{
  "1-1": 11,
  "1-2": {
    "2-1": "21"
  },
  "1-3": 13
}
"""
        def jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(json).getAsJsonObject()

        when:
        JsonObject result = classUnderTest.flatten(jsonObject)

        then:
        result.keySet().containsAll(["1-1", "1-2", "1-3", "2-1"])
    }
}
```

I have a gradle project with one subproject and a module-info.java

```
plugins {
    id "groovy"
    id "application"
    id "org.beryx.jlink" version "2.25.0"
    id "org.javamodularity.moduleplugin" version "1.8.10"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    log4jVersion = "2.17.2"
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.7.0") {
        exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"
        exclude group: "com.google.gson"
    }
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.2")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0")

    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:${log4jVersion}")
    runtimeOnly("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:${log4jVersion}")
    annotationProcessor("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:${log4jVersion}")
    runtimeOnly("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:${log4jVersion}")


    testImplementation("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.9")
    testImplementation("org.spockframework:spock-core:2.0-groovy-3.0")
}

application {
    mainClass = "com.pittacode.apihelper.Runner"
    mainModule = "com.pittacode.apihelper"
}

tasks.named("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    forceMerge "log4j", "jackson"
//    options = ["--bind-services"] // makes jre bigger but has everything, good way to test stuff
    launcher {
        name = "apihelper"
        jvmArgs = ["-Dlog4j.configurationFile=./log4j2.xml", "-Dlog4j2.debug=false"]
    }
    jpackage {
        if (org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().windows) {
            installerOptions += ["--win-per-user-install", "--win-dir-chooser", "--win-menu", "--win-shortcut"]
            imageOptions += ["--win-console"]
        }
    }
}

tasks.jlink.doLast {
    copy {
        from("src/main/resources")
        into("$buildDir/image/bin")
    }
}
```

This is the class

```
package com.pittacode.apihelper.json;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public final class JsonObjectFlattener {

    public JsonObjectFlattener() {
    }

    public JsonObject flatten(JsonObject o) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that in another specification class if I try to initiate another object (unrelated) it seems to create it just fine. That one has parameters so I tried adding some in the flattener as well but didn't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 1):

Well this was silly,

Like I mentioned I am using java modules and it seems that I need to export the packages that contain the classes I want to test.

```
module com.pittacode.apihelper {
    requires jdk.crypto.ec; // needed for ssl communication
    requires org.slf4j;
    requires java.net.http;
    requires java.sql;
    requires com.google.gson;
    requires json.path;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;

    exports com.pittacode.apihelper;
    exports com.pittacode.apihelper.json; // <-- this is the missing line
}
```